# Reopen a workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working in c# with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

I have a function used to open a workbook with excel. This workbook can be closed by user (or application). My problem is that I can't reopen this workbook.

```
Excel.Workbook Workbook;

private void OpenWorkbook(Excel.Application exApp)
{
    // Check if a workbook has been opened
    if (WorkBook != null)
    {
        // Create a workbook
        WorkBook = exApp.Workbooks.Add();
    }
    else
    {
        // Add workbook to excel application
        WorkBook = exApp.Workbooks.Add(WorkBook);
        /*
        => this part doesn't work
        Excel has been quit by user and I have a error : DisconnectedContext
        */

    }
}
```

How can I reconnect or recreate my workbook ?

Comment: Do you work with Excel.Visible = true oder false?

Comment: with Visible = true, user can see and modify the sheet

Comment: Did the below solution work for you?

Comment: I still can't reopen my closed workbook. Actually I found a workaround by saving the file path and opening a new workbook each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the `object Missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;`.
Try it like in this example: http://pastebin.com/xqhu9eCK